# Injecting only some properties, mocking others

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I am writing a unit test for a Bean that has some properties autowired in using spring.

Here is the bean:

```
public class Goober {

     @Autowired
     private ObjectX prop1;

     @Autowired
     private ObjectY prop2;


     //... rest of object
}
```

In my unit test, I'd like to Mock prop1 using jmockit, but have prop2 injected by spring. Here is what my test looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext-test.xml" })
public class GooberUT extends TestCase{

    @Tested @Autowired
    Goober goober;

    @Test
    public void gooberTest (@Injectable prop1) {


        // .. test and whatnot here
    }


    // .. setup/teardown etc
}
```

The problem here is that prop1 will be autowired by spring. If I remove the @Autowired annotation from the test, then prop1 will be mocked, but prop2 will be null.

How do I inject one property in Goober with jMockit, and Autowire the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let Spring inject prop1 and then override the prop1 value with ReflectionTestUtils' setProperty method and inject whatever you like programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Provided `ObjectY` is a class and not an interface, you can have the following test class:

```
public class GooberUT
{
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true)
    Goober goober;

    @Test
    public void gooberTest(@Injectable ObjectX prop1)
    {
        // .. test and whatnot here
    }

    // .. setup/teardown etc
}
```

With `@Tested(fullyInitialized = true)`, JMockit will instantiate and inject all fields in the tested object, recursively. Fields matching an `@Injectable`, though, will receive the mock instance.